# "This add-on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt" on Waterfox with xpinstall.signatures.required=false

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, waterfox

I'm trying to install an add-on:

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/887261/referer_control-1.31-an+fx.xpi

It works fine if I manually download it and then install it as a "temporary add-on". However, it does not work if I try to install it normally. I have set `xpinstall.signatures.required=false` (this is actually the default in Waterfox). I also tried setting `xpinstall.whitelist.required` to false, but to no avail.

This happens with many (almost all) add-ons at `addons.mozilla.org`, so I wonder if the recent signature changes have affected something.

Comment: If you open one of the files with a compression tool is the internal directory structure [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28494970/the-add-on-could-not-be-installed-because-it-appears-to-be-corrupt)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder if the recent signature changes have affected something.

The recent signature changes involved reissuing an expired certificate. Addon signatures were not re-generated – instead the same certificate was issued again, only with its expiry date updated.

Because its public key and metadata otherwise remain identical, it can be used to verify the old signatures – but, of course, only as long as you *actually have* the new certificate. For example, the hotfix distributed via Firefox Studies works by installing it into Firefox's main "CA certificates" database so that it would override the outdated certificate that's still bundled with addons themselves.

Other browsers which use Mozilla-signed addons must therefore also include this new certificate in order to successfully validate old addons. You can download it and manually import into Waterfox's "Authorities" tab (it's an intermediate cert, so it does not need any 'trust' checkboxes to be selected).

[image: (Screenshot of Firefox's "Certificate Manager" with the new signing CA highlighted)]

For reference, the certificate (which you can copy to a *.pem file and then import) is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Great; this worked! But isn't the point of `xpinstall.signatures.required=false` to make it not check signatures?

Comment: Perhaps in Waterfox it only allows a signature to be _absent_, but not invalid?

Comment: Also FYI a fix was [integral to Waterfox Classic 56.2.10](https://www.waterfox.net/blog/waterfox-56.2.10-release-download/).

Answer (score 0):

As written in the forum - http://tabmixplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=20043

workaround -

`You can use WFox classic, it's at v.56.3 and you can use all your 'legacy' exts., or use Basilisk, the same as the good old Fx.` makondo